# What about tags random and randomness?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What are the respective roles of [random](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random) and [randomness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness)? Do we need both, or any of them?

Related tags: [randomized-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomized-algorithms), [sampling](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling), [random-number-generator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-number-generator), [pseudo-random-generators](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-random-generators), [random-walks](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-walks), [random-graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-graphs)

Comment: I believe the correct solution is to toss an unbiased coin and use the tag "random" if it  comes up heads and "randomness" if it's tails.

Answer (score 9):

We definitely need at least one tag to cover randomized algorithms (that use randomness to do something) and one for random generators (that produce (pseudo)randomness).

For randomized algorithms, we have [randomized-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomized-algorithms), and more specific tags such as [random-walks](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-walks), [random-graphs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-graphs), [sampling](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling), etc. This seems fine to me.

For random generators, we have a tag [random-number-generator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-number-generator) and a more specialized tag [pseudo-random-generator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-random-generator), as well as [entropy](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entropy). Most uses of [random-number-generator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-number-generator) are about PRNG. I'm not sure if this tag is warranted on this site, but technically speaking it is a different topic.

Inasmuch as [random](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random)/[randomness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness) are warranted, I don't see any possible difference in meaning, only a stylistic choice. I'm for making [randomness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness) the main tags since we usually use nouns as tags (“this question is about randomness”). I have no strong feeling as to the ~70 questions with these tags should be disambiguated to one of the two sides of the randomness coin.

Comment: [tag:randomness] should be for questions about randomness (e.g., how much random bits are needed for an algorithm. How many samples of Bernoulli(p) are needed to in order to sample some distribution P,  etc.). Looking at the list of questions now tagged [tag:random] it seems this tag was used *in practice* as a synonyms of [tag:randomized-algorithm].

Comment: @RanG. So you'd say [tag:algorithm-analysis+randomness] for analysing the number of necessary random bits? Feels wrong, linguistically, but I don't have better idea.

Comment: @Raphael [tag:randomness] is wider, and includes in my eyes also primitives like extractors, etc. My main point was that [tag:random] should **not** be  synonyms of randomness, but instead of [tag:randomized-algorithm].

Comment: @RanG. I don't think assigning different meaning to an adjective and its noun is reasonable (at least in the context of tagging). Anyway, it seems as if you want to post your own answer.

Comment: @RanG. I agree that they're not synonyms. I would favour keeping "randomness", removing the "random" tag and individually retagging its 21 questions with whatever is most appropriate for that question.

Comment: Given the feedback so far, should we act?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other tag combinations, I think we should in addition to Gilles' answer go

[randomness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness) ← [randomized-algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomized-algorithms);

tag [algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) can be added to disambiguate.

In particular, I think there is little danger of confusing [randomness](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/randomness)+[algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) with [random-number-generator](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-number-generator); the latter are rarely random themselves